# What is the command to use to go to another statement?

Tags: c++

When the code input is wrong, I would want to redirect the user to the earlier statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

char customer;

cout<<"1- Residential customer"<<endl;
cout<<"2- Business customer"<<endl;
cin>>customer;

switch (customer)
{

case '1':
    {

        float code1, answer;




        cout<<"Input code:"<<endl; //123
        cin>>code1;

        if (code1 == 123)
        {
            cout<<"Access granted";
            goto label1;
        }

        else
        {
            cout<<"Access denied!";
            exit(0);

        }

label1:

        int ans, B, P;
        float basicServ, billProc, basicServ_Fee;
        billProc = 4.50;
        basicServ_Fee = 20.50;

        cout<<endl; //This whole statement loops continuously
        cout<<"Bill processing fee: $4.50"<<endl;
        cout<<"Choose your billing:"<<endl;
        cout<<"B- Basic service"<<endl;
        cout<<"P- Premium Channel"<<endl;
        cout<<"Choice:";
        cin>>ans;

        if (ans == 'B')
        {
            basicServ = billProc + basicServ_Fee;

            cout<<"Your bill: $"<< basicServ<<endl;
        }

        else
        {
            cout<<"Invalid input";
            goto label1;
        }


    }
}





 system("pause");
 return 0;

 }
```

I search that the command goto helps but when I tried doing it for the part when choosing between Basic Service and Premium Channel, it just produced an endless loop of

Choose your billing:

Bill processing fee -4.50

B- Basic service

P- Premium Channel

Invalid input

That's what happens when I try to input 'B'

What I don't understand is it worked fine here

```
if (code1 == 123)
        {
            cout<<"Access granted";
            goto label1;
        }
```

It redirected me to label1.
Am I doing something wrong? I'm still a beginner and trying to strengthen my basics. Help me.

Thank you

Edit: My code is not done yet and only up to the basic service

Comment: You shouldn't use `goto` in C++ unless you have a good reason (you don't). Also `ans` is an `int`. That will cause a problem.

Comment: To add to @kevin, you should definitely never ever use a goto inside of a switch statement in C or C++.

Comment: By the way, why are you using C++ at all? It is not (in my opinion) a good language for beginners.

Comment: C++ can be a good language for a beginner if the focus is on modern C++ and not C-style C++ (which includes gotos among many other things).

Comment: Goto is a bad idea - one might almost say harmful.

Comment: try not to think of goto label,  instead think function call.  Perhaps use the stuff you associate with "label1:" as the code of a function, i.e. "bool f1()"

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to keep repeating a block of code (printing the menu & accepting a choice) until a valid entry is made.  This is what loop statements (like `while`) are for.  That is,

```
while ( something ) {
    code
}
```

will evaluate `something` and, if it is true, will then execute *code* & repeat the process; otherwise, it skips over code & proceeds to whatever comes next.

You could, for example, have a variable named `done` and initialize it to 0 (because you aren't done yet); if `ans` is such that you don't need to ask for a menu choice again, you would set `done` to 1, which would cause the loop to stop.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using goto you should use a loop. Try the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    char customer;
    float code1;

    while(true){
        cout<<"1- Residential customer"<<endl;
        cout<<"2- Business customer"<<endl;
        cin>>customer;

        cout<<"Input code:"<<endl;
        cin>>code1;

        if (code1 == 123){
            cout<<"Access granted"<<endl;
            break;
        }

        else{
            cout<<"Access denied!"<<endl;
        }
    }

    // do stuff
     system("pause");
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: note there is a second goto, so a second while loop is needed too.

Comment: @Wimmel: A second loop is not *needed*, although it can be implemented that way.